# How to manually order libraries in a VisualStudio solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, solution

I have a VisualStudio 2022 solution with multiple libraries in it.
I'm using common application layers (DAL, Business, Presentation).

Right now this is what it looks like in the solution explorer.

[image: current result]

Instead, **I would like the libraries to be ordered by their layer rather than alphabetically.**

Like this:

1. DAL
2. Business
3. Presentation

Is there a way to manipulate the `sln` or `csproj` files to achieve what I want?

Comment: You can add folders to sort your projects (these are just virtual and don't need to represent folders on disk).

Comment: Yeah I know, but it would add an extra layer that I prefer to avoid.

Comment: Then I don't think you can change this behavior.